# Mappers Launched during a job execution

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

Hive Partition has 4 files as follows:

1. I have a file of 256mb - occupies 2 blocks on HDFS
2. another file of 150mb - occupies 2 blocks on HDFS
3. another file of 260 mb - occupies 3 blocks on HDFS
4. another file of 64mb -  occupies 1 block on HDFS

HDFS default block size is 128mb

If a mapreduce operation is performed on the ablove partition
what is my inptsplit size?
How many mappers will be launched?

Will my job has only 4 mappers because in small files the mapper are created on number of small files?

Will my job have 8 mapers because i have my 4 files spread over 8 blocks on HDFS
Will my 4 block(second file is 128mb(3rd block)+22mb(4th block)) which has only 22mb will be combined with last file and forms 1 inputsplit?

I tried searching many blogs, I still have this confusion